# Understanding why MongoDB uses more RAM than the allowed wiredTigerCacheSizeGB

Tags: mongodb, memory, wiredtiger

My mongod command

```bash
mongod --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 5
```

In practice, I'm getting mongo instance to use even up to 8.6 GB (on a VM with 50 GB RAM)

Indexes are using about 100 MB (checked with `db.stats()`)

tcmalloc information:

```bash
MALLOC:     3776745552 ( 3601.8 MiB) Bytes in use by application
MALLOC: +   4744544256 ( 4524.8 MiB) Bytes in page heap freelist
MALLOC: +     20067616 (   19.1 MiB) Bytes in central cache freelist
MALLOC: +      3584128 (    3.4 MiB) Bytes in transfer cache freelist
MALLOC: +     12470800 (   11.9 MiB) Bytes in thread cache freelists
MALLOC: +     22544384 (   21.5 MiB) Bytes in malloc metadata
MALLOC:   ------------
MALLOC: =   8579956736 ( 8182.5 MiB) Actual memory used (physical + swap)
MALLOC: +     29933568 (   28.5 MiB) Bytes released to OS (aka unmapped)
MALLOC:   ------------
MALLOC: =   8609890304 ( 8211.0 MiB) Virtual address space used
MALLOC:
MALLOC:          21650              Spans in use
MALLOC:             59              Thread heaps in use
MALLOC:           4096              Tcmalloc page size
```

The server had been running for 3 days.

How can I tell why mongo is consuming more memory than the allowed cache size? Is there any way to manually free up the "page heap freelist"?

The command output is recommending `Call ReleaseFreeMemory() to release freelist memory to the OS`, but I don't think I can actually do that out of the process.

MongoDB version is `4.4.1`, I'm using `mongo:4.4.1-bionic` docker image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum cache size is just that - a limit on the size of the cache used by the underlying storage engine.

If you run queries, sort things, make connections, etc, those all require memory outside of the cache.

MongoDB uses tcmalloc for memory management, which doesn't immediately release memory back to the OS when the program calls `free`.

You can adjust how tcmalloc releases memory with the `tcmallocAggressiveMemoryDecommit` server parameter added here:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16829

Comment: Thanks. This sounds good although its very minimally documented. I did find this article more enlightening: https://mongoing.com/archives/34751

Comment: Couple more links: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37541?spm=a2c4e.10696291.0.0.513919a4vVwFUw https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24303